# Make switch directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to pass in a `$scope` that I want to change the value on.

These are two switch button on the same page that.

[image]

**View**

```
<div class="input">
    <switch state="false" toggle="user.emailNotification">
        <flip></flip>
    </switch>
</div>

<div ng-click="saveNotifySettings()" class="button fill primary">Vista</div>
```

**Controller**

```
  app.controller('notifySettingCtrl', function($scope, Users){
    Users.get().$promise.then(function(data) {
      $scope.user = data;
      console.log($scope.user.emailNotification);
    });
    $scope.saveNotifySettings = function() {
        console.log("PUT the new value for the switch");
    };
  });
```

When I press the button the state changes from `false` to `true`
First I want to init the state with the existing value from `$scope.user.emailNotification` and then change it and pass the changes to the controller.

The beginning of the my directive.

**switch directive**

```
(function() {
  define(['angular', 'app', 'underscore'], function(angular, app, _) {
    app.directive('switch', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
          value: '&toggle',
        },
        link: function(scope, element) {
          var x = scope.value();

          element.bind('mouseenter', function() {
            console.log(x);
          });

          var $element = angular.element(element),
              uniqueId = _.uniqueId('switch-'),
              state = $element.attr('state');

          state = typeof state === 'undefined' ? false : state;

          $element.data('uniqueId',uniqueId)
            .attr('state',state)
            .attr('alive',true);

          $element.on('click.'+uniqueId,function(){
            if (state === true) {
              $(this).attr('state',false);
              state = false;
            } else {
              $(this).attr('state',true);
              state = true;
            }
          });
        }
      };
    });
  });
}).call(this);
```

I'm very new at creating directives, so any help is well appreciated.
I have spend way to much time at this and it getting frustrating :/

**Update**:

I have created http://jsfiddle.net/HuLn4/. I have taken the pointers from you and refactored.

TLDR: I'm trying to create directive by sending in the model that I want to change in this case user.emailNotification and when the  element is clicked on it changes the value from true/false and false/true and stores it back to the controllers $scope.user so it can be PUT to server and the state attribute is only to tell the look on the switch and for the initialize on the button ( on / off ).

Comment: If you throw it in a JSFiddle of Plunker we could clean it up and test it a lot easier for you.

Comment: I will try, but is all hooked up in requirejs and more.

Comment: Be aware that you will need to call scope.$apply after any jQuery event is handled in your directive so that angular knows of any change.

Comment: When passing attributes to `scope` make sure you use the correct "sign."  `&` is used to execute a function or expression in the parent scope - usually you'll want to pass a function name from parent to directive using this.  In your case `user.emailNotification` is data, you'll want to bind that with either `@` or `=` the latter being a 2-way data-bind that will change the value in the directive as well as the parent.

Comment: Also, the directive's `link` function receives a list of attributes as a parameter, there is no need to do `$element.attr(...)` the link function definition should look like this: `link: function(scope,element,attr)`  there are more parameters available as well but don't get used as often - `controller,transclude`

Comment: I have added the Jsfiddle.